# cmd script to copy files based on month

Tags: windows, date, cmd

I am writing a script to copy file from a ftp server to local.i am able to use cmd command to download file etc. My only problem now is copying file to destination.
I want copy file based on month.If the current month is odd(like jan,mar,may,july...etc) then file should copy to D:\ if the month is even(like feb,apr etc..) the file should be copied to E:\ How can i do this by using cmd command script.I think i should get current date and extract month and do it on the basis of month.But how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
rem Next line assume that %date% format is MM/DD/YYYY:
rem (change by tokens=2 if format is DD/MM/YYYY)
for /F "tokens=1 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do set /A parity=1%%a %% 2
if %parity% equ 1 (
   set drive=D:\
) else (
   set drive=E:\
)
copy the_file... %drive%
```